# Jquery upload (starts new Session)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor, upload

I'm using MVC 3.0 razor and have page where authenticated users can upload file, but when they press upload file button new session starts...

how do I can resolve this problem?

jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load (
        function () {
             $("#file-uploader").fileUpload({
                'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Upload File',
                'script': 'Chat/Upload',
                'multi': true,
                'auto': true,
                'forUser': @Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"])
            });
        }
```

);
     </script>

<div id="file-uploader">
 
    <noscript>
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
    </noscript>
  </div>

Comment: i don't know MVC3 razor, but this line does nothing: `$.session` and lacks a semi colon. maybe you mistyped a function call ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the plugin you are using depends on Flash and it doesn't send the session and forms authentication cookies along with the request. Here's a [blog post](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/12/mvc-file-upload-using-uploadify-with.html) which illustrates a possible way to handle this scenario. It uses Uploadify but you should be able to adapt it to your plugin. The idea is to send the session id and authentication cookie value as additional parameters so that the server can reconstruct the actual Session and User objects.